# Google Appscript problem with export to PDF when used by another user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been making a sheet that helps me with the process of making invoices throught the "Invoice" tab on the sheet I will link below. Yes - I made sure to get rid of any info, do not worry.

The problem I have, is that if I try to export the Invoice tab to a PDF, this works as intended and the file is automatically named correctly following a certain structure in Appscript.
However, when someone elses uses this sheet, for some reason it saves the file on the wrong name (happens to always be the name of one customer above the one you are invoicing under. In my sheet, meaning that if they try to make an invoice for Example2, the file will save and give it a name based on info from Example1 **even when the invoice tab is properly showing all data.**

I am lost and looking to see if anyone can see what is happening.

File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TF1xncuX_P47dSvQnrrbZIdOpTG20rQ4UvNpywiGwbs/edit?usp=sharing

Appscript:

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save PDF", functionName:"generatePdf"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Export', submenu);
}

function generatePdf() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var titleName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var pdfName = titleName;

  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true) ;
```

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that the sheet name of the active sheet is used as the filename of `theBlob`. If you want to use the constant sheet name, how about directly put the specific sheet name to `sheetName` of `var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);`? But if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Is it possible your friend is pressing the Invoice button before committing a change to the cell?  Try this: type 1 under FACTUURNUMMER, then press Enter. Then type 2 in that cell, and without pressing enter, immediately press the Invoice button.  The script will run with the example 1 data, because the value 2 was not yet committed.  Make sure they press enter in the cell (or click away) before pressing the Invoice button.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue here, but I have found it useful to call `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` *before* generating a pdf (i.e. before your line that starts `var theBlob = ...`), to force commit any changes.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtlee , the issue has been resolved, thank you for your comments. This was a user-end problem and I've passed them on to chill down on the executions of the files. I did add the extra flush however, for good measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, thank you for your comments. This was a user-end problem and I've passed them on to chill down on the executions of the files. I did add the extra flush however, for good measure like mentioned above.